# Creating actual full screen sections with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create full screen sections for my web page, each section has a different color, the thing is that when I scroll, there is no way to display the section so that the colors fill the screen, what could I change so that each section fills the whole screen?

HTML:

```
<section class="first"> 

</section>

<section class="second">  

</section>
<section class="third">  

</section>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  height: 100vh;
}
.first {
  background-color:#834940;
}

.second {
  background-color:#291411;
}
.third {
  background-color:#834940;
}
/* Hide scrollbars */

html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  
    background: transparent; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0e8o.png)

Comment: you need some javascript

Comment: Could you show me a code example as I have never used it?

Comment: Create this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naL42kr1/) and it works fine for me. Can you show what happens when you try it? Some screenshots of the problem should help.

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro I have added a third section so you can see that the middle one shows a bit of color from the first or last section, I included a screenshot

Comment: Thats because the scroll amount doesn't match with the screen height, so you scroll 120px per "scroll", 3 times it's 360px, if the screen is 400px, it's going to show 40px of the first section

Comment: Do you maybe have a solution to change the amount of px per scroll so it won't show colors from other sections?

Comment: It can be done with javascript, I will try to answer with an example

Comment: That would be nice, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**: https://codepen.io/ckor/pen/lBnxh

**HTML**

```
<section class="intro">  
  <div class="content">
    <h1>You can create full screen sections without javascript.</h1>
    <p>The height is set to 90vh, that means 90% height.</p>
 </div>
</section>

<section>  
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Resize your browser and see how they adapt.</h1>
 </div>
</section>

<section>  
  <div class="content">
    <h1>It's amazing and fast.</h1>
 </div>
</section>

<section>  
  <div class="content">
    <h1>See the <a href="http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units">browser support.</a></h1>
 </div>
</section>
```

**SCSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body {
  margin: 0; 
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 7%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: none;
  background-color: #373B44;
  height: 100vh;

  &:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background-color: #FE4B74;
  }
}

.intro {
  height: 90vh;
}

.content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #C3CAD9;
}

a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #373B44;
  position: relative;

  &:hover{ 
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

  &:active {
    top: 1px;
  }
}

footer {
  padding: 1% 5%;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #373B44;
  color: white;

  a {
    color: #FE4B74;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: In this example you can also see a little bit of color at the bottom from the next section. Even if you try to position one section manually. I was looking for a fix so that every section fills the screen when scrolling

Comment: @Seb Just change `90vh` to `100vh`. If you want sections to "stick" to viewport when scrolling, you'll need snap points: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap_Points

Comment: Because in the example intro section used "90vh", try to change to "100vh".

Answer (score 0):

It shows a little bit of color because the scroll amount doesn't match with the screen height, so you scroll 120px per "scroll", 3 times it's 360px, if the screen is 400px, it's going to show 40px of the first section, another scroll and it's 480px, now you see 80px from the third section.

Usually it's not a good idea to change the scroll behaviour, so keep that in mind while using this solution. Everytime you scroll it will show a different section.

It listens for the scroll event, it prevents it and then scrolls to the next section. DON'T use this if you have more content than just sections.

```js
window.onload = function () {
 var currentSectionIndex = 0;
 var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');

 function onScroll(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var scrollDir = (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail);
  if (scrollDir < 0) {
   currentSectionIndex++;
  } else {
   currentSectionIndex--;
  }

  if (currentSectionIndex < 0) {
   currentSectionIndex = 0;
  }
  if (currentSectionIndex >= sections.length) {
   currentSectionIndex = sections.length-1;
  }

  var section = sections[currentSectionIndex];
  if (section) {
   section.scrollIntoView();
  }
 }

 window.onmousewheel = onScroll;
};
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: none;
    height: 100vh;
}

.first {
    background-color:#834940;
}
.second {
    background-color:#291411;
}
.third {
    background-color:#834940;
}


/* Hide scrollbars */
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  
    background: transparent; 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<section class="section first"></section>

<section class="section second"></section>

<section class="section third"></section>
```